"Cannot find name" while using typescript in Next Js
These errors are shown
What should I do to resolve this problem.
I have also gone through so many other posts and made some changes, reloaded the window but none of them helped.
something like "initialising JS/TS feature" runs as I open the layout.tsx and after this the error starts coming.
Also it doesn't affect the web page it is getting rendered and working perfectly.
Also this error is coming only in layout.tsx.
All the extensions are .tsx, changed this also "jsx": "react-jsx",

Try starting over and using https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/create-next-app. Nextjs supports typescript out of the box, so you might have gone through a non-standard setup. If the errors only show up in vscode, maybe you screwed up something in your vscode settings, but that seems less likely.

Okay, I'm gonna try that.
Thanks!
